# what does ignoreFieldChange and fireSlavingSync properties means in Suitescript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I m new in development and Suitescript. While creating a new field in my `userevernt` script, I came to know of some properties: like `ignoreFieldChange: true/false` and  `fireSlavingSync: true/false`.

Can anyone explain to me because I am so confused when to put them as true, when false and when just don't include them?

e.g.

```
objRecord.setValue({
  fieldId: 'item',
  value: true,
  ignoreFieldChange: true,
  fireSlavingSync: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot steeve! This time i understood the reason of using this.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it's solved your issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options prevent additional scripts firing when you set a field value with a client script.

Ie. If you have a `fieldChanged` client script running on field `custbodymyfield`, when you set this field value, the `fieldChanged` script would fire.

Sometimes this has the potential to create a loop,  so we use `ignoreFieldChange` when we setValue if we do NOT want the fieldChange script to run.

For the other option,  a good explanation is here (the last answer)

https://netsuitehub.com/forums/topic/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-the-fireslavingsync-parameter-is-such-as-with-currentrecord-setvalue/